# Convert String containing letters to Int efficiently - Apache Spark

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

I am working with a dataset that has users as Strings (ie. B000GKXY4S). I would like to convert each of these users to int, so I can use  Rating(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Double) class in Apache Spark ALS. What is the most efficient way to do this? Preferably using Spark Scala functions or python native functions.

Comment: If the strings are composed of 8-bit characters, you could consider them to be base-256 numbers. This will give you a unique integer value for each one, although it might be huge number (which Python can easily handle).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want any matchable String to an int - `String.hashCode()`. However you will have to deal with possible hash collisions. Alternatively you'd have to convert each character to its int value and append (not add) all of these together.